# With kafka tell in producer witch consumer is allowed to consume

Tags: apache-kafka

I have 4 Services A, B, C & D that send the same object in a ONE topic.
Then I have 4 other Services W, X, Y & Z that consume messages in the same previous topic.
My question is it possible that:

- W read only messages sent by A
- X read only messages sent by B
- Y read only messages sent by C
- Z read only messages sent by D

How?

didn't try any thing. All I think about is groups but with groupes we can rebalance only not specify for each message witch group can read the message.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible; Kafka consumers will always read all events on a topic.

Even if you define a conditional filter in the consumer code, that still requires fetching the bytes from the broker, deserializing the data, then seeing "who sent this message?"